# Setting up Facebook in simulator

Tags: xcode, facebook, setting

guys 
I want to set my simulator account twitter is ok
When I press Facebook, the screen just stuck and can't get into the facebook account seeting
how to fix this problem thx for the help !!!!
btw my xcode is v5.1.1

Comment: "reset contend and setting" in simulator's menu...

Comment: i tried that and it didn't work... :(